# How can I pass a function as writing when using the write function?

Tags: python, function

Hi I am trying to write to a file a list of sorted records. As shown in the code below, the first function "print_all_records(list)" sorts a list of data into a table. Now for the second function I want to write that data into a  file (first parameter) "backup.txt". I want the data to be in the same table format as in the first function.

This is what the first function produces:

[image: currently this is what the first function produces.]

This is what the backup txt file looks like:
[image]

I want to know how I can fix this and also if I can pass the first function inside the brackets of the writefile

```
def print_all_records(list):
    
    ttl= "Store Id"  
    emplys= "Employees"
    sub_name= "Suburb"
    sale_vol = "Sale volume"

    print(f"{ttl:>1} {emplys:>15} {sub_name:>15} {sale_vol:>20}") #displaying a heading

    print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------") #manually printing a dashed line

    for rec in list:
        print(f"{rec[0]:>1}{rec[1]:>15} {rec[2]:>20}{rec[3]:>20}") 

      

def write_data(filename, records):
    with open(filename, "w") as writefile:
      for rec in records:
        writefile.write(f"{rec[0]:>1}{rec[1]:>15}{rec[2]:>20}{rec[3]:>20}")
```

Comment: If this is just a backup file, consider some other format like CSV. Is there an advantage to it looking the same as the table? A CSV can be used with many tools.

Comment: Remember that `write` does not add a newline.  You have to add one yourself.  However, the best advice is to write it as a CSV.  They are easier to handle than fixed columns.

Comment: And if you wand to use the same function, do `def print_all_records(list, file=sys.stdout):`, and then do `print(..., file=file)`.

Comment: Looks like you're showing us a screenshot of the text in an editor with word wrap turned on, and it's really all one big line, because the script doesn't write line endings. [Why you should not upload data as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) - the line ending in `:>20}"` should end in `:>20}\n"`

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, the main objective is to use the write function and the name of the file its stored in does not matter.